# Partitions not showing after installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, filesystems

Yesterday, I installed the Windows 7. I found out that my other disks (partitions) automatically disappeared from my computer and only showing C disk.

I tried to defragment, hide/unhide the disk, also `cmd` » `diskpart` » `list volume` but still can't see any trail of my other disks.

But when I go to Device Manager and check Disk Drives » Volumes » Populate, I can see that there is:

- Disk: Disk0
- Type: basic
- Status: online
- Partition style: Master Boot Record (MBR)
- Capacity: 305245MB
- Unallocated space: 0 MB
- Reserved space: 0 MB

Volumes only shows

- C: 305245 MB.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: What was the OS you previously had on the disk?

Comment: Did you mess with the existing partitioning scheme during installation?

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in tool to see what you have currently...

1. Right click "Computer" in the start menu and choose Manage.
2. Go to "Disk Management" in the tree .. this will show partitions and disks.
3. Post a screenshot of what you see after it loads (it will take ~5 mins).

Answer (score 0):

If your previous OS installation was linux then your partitions will be formatted to ext3 or ext4 - these formats are not recognised by windows.